# Gradle 2.13 hooks up the wrong JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I recently updated my Gradle to 2.13 and it doesn't work like the previous version that I used. In my `build.gradle` files, I use the following setting:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
```

This is because I'm maintaining a library that should be backwards-compatible. When I was using `gradle eclipse` command to generate Eclipse project, it used to set compliance level to `1.6` (as expected), and hook up my system Java 8 JRE library, thus generating no warnings.

However, the new Gradle version hooks up `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]`, which generates the following warning:

> Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.6. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

I know how to remove the warning *manually* (remove the incorrect system library, add default Java 8 system lib), but I want to know if there's a way of achieving the previous Gradle behavior without having to modify anything in the IDE itself.

Is there a way to force Gradle to hook up a specific JRE system library when generating a new Eclipse project with the standard eclipse plugin? In my case, I want it to use the library from JRE located at `JAVA_HOME` rather than forcing a library according to the `sourceCompatibility` setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer through the Gradle forum.

The previous behavior "was incorrect and caused many users problems", as you get warnings when using new language *features*, but you can still use new *classes* without any problems during development.

However, this warning can be silenced:

> If you really don't care about using the correct JDK, you can deactivate this warning in the workspace settings (Java -> Compiler -> Building -> No strictly compatible JRE). I strongly recommend using the correct JDK though.